# Where to find credit risk data set?

Tags: dataset, finance

I am starting my thesis in Credit Risk Modelling very soon, but I realise it's really hard to get some real data. Does anyone know is this kind of data publicly available or I need to purchase it from somewhere.

Just a little bit more detail of the kind of data I am looking for: Preferably it has couple thousand companies with the record of whether they have successfully paid off their loans, and it should also have the companies' key accounting/financial ratios(like working capital/total assets ratio, sales/total assets ratio etc).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's highly regulated area. It's very unlikely you will find that.

Comment: Sorry: off-topic.  See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486/suitable-venue-to-help-find-specific-statistical-data .

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

- Prosper and other peer-to-peer lending sites sometimes make their data available.  Not precisely what you are looking for, but it has a similar flavor.
- Wharton (U. Pennsylvania) makes tons of data available through [WRDS](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/).  It's most definitely not free, but many institutions subscribe to it and yours may as well.  At very least you could look there for the existence of a dataset and try to negotiate directly with the data providers.

Comment: thank you so so much, lucky for me my university does subscribe to WRDS.